# I would like to recover the value of each String

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I get one sentence per byte block and I would like to recover the value of these string

i tried to use regex.

```
String stringReceived = intent.getStringExtra("data");
                    //check that the data comes from a sensor
                    if (stringReceived.contains("ID") && 
stringReceived.contains("Value")) {
                        //sorts the received data using regex
                        Pattern pattern = 
Pattern.compile(.*Timestamp=(\\d+).*ID=(\\d+).*Value=(\\d+));
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringReceived);

                        while (matcher.find()) {
                            String timestampS = matcher.group(1);
                            String idS = matcher.group(2);
                            String valueS = matcher.group(3);
   }
}
```

I receive my data in this form:

```
I/RECEIVER: [1/1/0 4
I/RECEIVER: :8:32] T
I/RECEIVER: imestamp
I/RECEIVER: =9466997
I/RECEIVER: 12 ID=4 
I/RECEIVER: Value=24
I/RECEIVER: 43
```

I would like something like this ; 
timestamp is: 548468788
ID is : 5
Value us : 545

Answer (score 0):

You can simply process each line and remove the part you don't need with simple String functions, eg substring() or even replace() :

```
line = line.replace("I/RECEIVER: ", "");
```

Then process the resulting value as needed.